# Additional .m file within same class

Tags: xcode, cocoa, class

In Cocoa/xCode, I have a class which is in a huge .m file and would like to split the .m file in 2 .m files but still being from the same class. So I can call [self myFunctionInSecond.mfile] from the first .m file.

How can I do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can `#import` or `#include` the second file into the first, so everything's in a single class.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but in my second .m I have some functions and when compiling, xcode tells me "Missing context for method declaration". Should I add any header in the second .m ?

Comment: If you include the second file in the first, inside the @impementation/@end of the first (and with no such statements in the second) then the compiler would treat it as a single file.

Comment: Thanks ! In addition to that, I needed to exclude the 2nd .m from the Compile Sources list.

Comment: True.  You could name it with a different suffix, but then the editor wouldn't recognize the language, I suppose.

Comment: How about using [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)?

Comment: Just found another a small issue with using this external .m file, i.e. the application does not stop at breakpoints set in this .m file...